# Increment a value when conditions are met, otherwise set to zero

Tags: linq

Given a list of strings, I'd like to create a list of the following object

```
    class LineInfo
    {
        public string line { get; set; }

        public bool isSearchMatch { get; set; }
        public int searchMatchNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Where I'd like searchMatchNumber to have 1 for the 1st match, 2 for the 2nd, etc. Otherwise it can be zero

I set this up like so

```
IEnumerable<string> allLines;   //pulled in from somewhere

        IEnumerable<LineInfo> logInfoLines = allLines.Select((l, i) => new LineInfo
        {
            line = l,
            isSearchMatch = l.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        });
```

How can I set searchMatchNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ queries should not cause side effects like this. If you'd add an `OrderBy` you'd get a different result. I wouldn't use LINQ for this, you could provide a method:

```
class LineInfo
{
    public string line { get; set; }
    public bool isSearchMatch { get; set; }
    public int searchMatchNumber { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<LineInfo> GetSearchResult(IEnumerable<string> allLines, string search)
    {
        int matchCounter = 0;
        var lineInfoList = new List<LineInfo>();

        foreach (string line in allLines)
        {
            bool isMatch = line.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            var li = new LineInfo
            {
                line = line,
                isSearchMatch = isMatch,
                searchMatchNumber = isMatch ? ++matchCounter : -1 // or whatever
            };
            lineInfoList.Add(li);
        }

        return lineInfoList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried your first approach, but I end up the a count that doesn't start at zero for some reason. I had wanted to avoid looping as I'll be dealing with thousands of lines, but your 2nd approach is working fine for me.Thanks

Comment: @user2436996: well, do you think that LINQ doesn't use loops?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how linq does what it does :)

Comment: @user2436996: it uses loops which you don't see. The "deferred execution"(lazy evaluation) is realized with state-machines(read about `yield`). That's why LINQ sometimes seems to be more efficient because people measure the time to create a query and not it's actual execution(for example if you append `ToList()` to a query).